# How should I handle aggregated values in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I see that Firestore has [count, sum and average operators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries) that calculate aggregated values on the server.

But there are also two documented solutions for [calculated aggregated values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) and [keeping distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters).

What is the difference between these solutions? And when should I use one or the other?

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR: the built-in operators perform read-time aggregation, while the documented solutions perform write-time aggregations.

---

#### History - How did we get here

When Firestore was initially released it had no support for any aggregation operations, such as counting documents. While this is not uncommon in NoSQL databases, lots of developers were asking how to then handle such operations - which is why the solutions on [aggregations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) and [distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) were documented.

These solutions aggregate values at write-time, meaning that you:

- Store the aggregated value somewhere, typically in a document in Firestore.
- Update the relevant count/sum/average every time a relevant write operation happens.
- Read the aggregated value (or listen to it) when you need it.

While these solutions work well, they require quite some planning and work from the developer.

Since then Firestore has been adding operators that allow [read-time aggregation operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries): first `count()` was added in late 2022, and then `sum()` and `average()` were added in late 2023.

---

#### Write-time aggregations and read-time aggregations

Now that Firestore's aggregation operators (count, sum, and average) have been out for a while, I've developed a certain way of describing them.

The new operators allow you to perform **read-time aggregation** across multiple documents. They're much more efficient than reading the full documents, because they can work from just the data in your indexes. And since this is much cheaper for us to execute, these operators are offered at a fraction (1/1000th) of the cost of reading the full documents.

---

#### When to use what approach for aggregated values

The existing solutions offer **write-time aggregation** across multiple documents. While this requires more up-front work than the read-time operators, they are still useful when:

- You have to aggregate over a lot of documents.

  The read-time count operator timed out at around 40 million documents when I tested: [How fast is counting documents in Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75317067/how-fast-is-counting-documents-in-cloud-firestore)
- A lot of users need to access the aggregate values.

  While the aggregation operators are much cheaper than reading full documents, counting millions of documents for millions of individual users still adds up to $$$.
- You want to get real-time updates of the aggregated values or want to access these values while offline.

  Read-time aggregation operators currently don't support listeners, nor are they available offline, while write-time aggregations are just values in normal documents.

On the other hand, for me the new read-time aggregation operators are more convenient when:

- You don't know ahead of time what aggregated values you may need.

  If you find yourself consistently needing to ad-hoc query the data, consider using a data source that is more tailored for that use-case, such as BigQuery.
- You need to count a reasonable number of documents for a reasonable number of users.
- You want to generate a periodic report with aggregated values.

Comment: Nice answer puf!

Comment: Yep, great answer, puf.

Comment: So If I already have a production db, and I decide that I want to sum or average some field into my newly created "aggergation/mycollection" collection. should I use the average function once, then let my cloud function update the average for new document writes, just like the old days? or is that not a vible approach?

Comment: Using the aggregation functions to seed (or periodically update) stored aggregates is a valid approach 