# How to increase the max allowed requests for a Firestore-App?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Our dashboard app monitors roughly 10,000 documents coming from 1000 snapshot listeners in real time on the client side. Everything works fine until around one hour in, we start to get "Too many outstanding requests" errors. This is not really predictable, sometimes it works for five hours, sometimes only 15 minutes.

At this point, it would be hard to move to server functions, so: Is there a way to increase the max allowed requests in Firestore?

```
11:20:33.739  [2023-11-30T10:20:33.739Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WatchChangeAggregator Detected inactive target 5502
11:20:33.739  [2023-11-30T10:20:33.739Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WatchChangeAggregator Detected inactive target 5504
11:20:33.739  [2023-11-30T10:20:33.739Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): MemoryPersistence Starting transaction: Get last remote snapshot version
11:20:33.739  [2023-11-30T10:20:33.739Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): MemoryPersistence Starting transaction: Apply remote event
11:20:33.766  [2023-11-30T10:20:33.766Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): MemoryPersistence Starting transaction: notifyLocalViewChanges
11:20:33.768  [2023-11-30T10:20:33.767Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WatchChangeAggregator Detected inactive target 204
WatchChangeAggregator Detected inactive target 205
```

...

```
11:20:33.866  [2023-11-30T10:20:33.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WatchChangeAggregator Detected inactive target 5500
11:20:33.866  [2023-11-30T10:20:33.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WatchChangeAggregator Detected inactive target 5502
11:20:33.866  [2023-11-30T10:20:33.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WatchChangeAggregator Detected inactive target 5504
11:20:33.866  [2023-11-30T10:20:33.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): MemoryPersistence Starting transaction: Get last remote snapshot version
11:20:33.866  [2023-11-30T10:20:33.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): MemoryPersistence Starting transaction: Apply remote event
11:20:33.892  [2023-11-30T10:20:33.892Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): MemoryPersistence Starting transaction: notifyLocalViewChanges
11:20:33.894  [2023-11-30T10:20:33.894Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): MemoryPersistence Starting transaction: Release target
11:20:33.894  [2023-11-30T10:20:33.894Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): PersistentStream close with error: FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Too many outstanding requests.
11:20:33.895  [2023-11-30T10:20:33.894Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Too many outstanding requests.
```

Another log:

```
WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"targetChange":{"targetChangeType":"CURRENT","targetIds":[108],"resumeToken":"CgkIo9Kd9MDrggM=","readTime":"2023-11-30T10:24:28.916003Z"}}
11:24:30.865  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.865Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"filter":{"targetId":166,"count":10,"unchangedNames":{"bits":{"bitmap":"Hoim1K4eUNurMP5/GsZ5DZLsbp/CbB3v460H","padding":5},"hashCount":15}}}
11:24:30.865  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.865Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"targetChange":{"targetChangeType":"CURRENT","targetIds":[166],"resumeToken":"CgkIo9Kd9MDrggM=","readTime":"2023-11-30T10:24:28.916003Z"}}
11:24:30.865  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.865Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"filter":{"targetId":132,"count":9,"unchangedNames":{"bits":{"bitmap":"DugrP2CKoOu/uvabPraCX+mDmPBcINM3","padding":1},"hashCount":15}}}
11:24:30.865  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.865Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"targetChange":{"targetChangeType":"CURRENT","targetIds":[132],"resumeToken":"CgkIo9Kd9MDrggM=","readTime":"2023-11-30T10:24:28.916003Z"}}
11:24:30.865  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.865Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"filter":{"targetId":174,"count":5,"unchangedNames":{"bits":{"bitmap":"YUGsfwj49ELfo/UyGA==","padding":3},"hashCount":14}}}
11:24:30.865  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.865Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"targetChange":{"targetChangeType":"CURRENT","targetIds":[174],"resumeToken":"CgkIo9Kd9MDrggM=","readTime":"2023-11-30T10:24:28.916003Z"}}
11:24:30.865  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.865Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"filter":{"targetId":114,"count":10,"unchangedNames":{"bits":{"bitmap":"5V/sJKeLOx0pPHxHS62g6uTRcTtfOtDPMVoH","padding":5},"hashCount":15}}}
11:24:30.866  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"targetChange":{"targetChangeType":"CURRENT","targetIds":[114],"resumeToken":"CgkIo9Kd9MDrggM=","readTime":"2023-11-30T10:24:28.916003Z"}}
11:24:30.866  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"filter":{"targetId":118,"count":2,"unchangedNames":{"bits":{"bitmap":"8/jAQxM=","padding":3},"hashCount":13}}}
11:24:30.866  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"targetChange":{"targetChangeType":"CURRENT","targetIds":[118],"resumeToken":"CgkIo9Kd9MDrggM=","readTime":"2023-11-30T10:24:28.916003Z"}}
11:24:30.866  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"filter":{"targetId":158,"count":10,"unchangedNames":{"bits":{"bitmap":"36Madb2sy9MPEsouXNmw6cN9aaToXjHjhncB","padding":5},"hashCount":15}}}
11:24:30.866  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"targetChange":{"targetChangeType":"CURRENT","targetIds":[158],"resumeToken":"CgkIo9Kd9MDrggM=","readTime":"2023-11-30T10:24:28.916003Z"}}
11:24:30.866  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"filter":{"targetId":188,"count":4,"unchangedNames":{"bits":{"bitmap":"U3ZN7yrtonRnCw==","padding":1},"hashCount":14}}}
11:24:30.866  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"targetChange":{"targetChangeType":"CURRENT","targetIds":[188],"resumeToken":"CgkIo9Kd9MDrggM=","readTime":"2023-11-30T10:24:28.916003Z"}}
11:24:30.866  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"filter":{"targetId":154,"count":15,"unchangedNames":{"bits":{"bitmap":"3ZqwYrjrLyw0mf41hHSzeVyxz0UHWE6HSutk2XMNZgKHre5glAc8/BgD","padding":5},"hashCount":15}}}
11:24:30.866  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"targetChange":{"targetChangeType":"CURRENT","targetIds":[154],"resumeToken":"CgkIo9Kd9MDrggM=","readTime":"2023-11-30T10:24:28.916003Z"}}
11:24:30.866  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"filter":{"targetId":128,"count":10,"unchangedNames":{"bits":{"bitmap":"j5UXY0H/5IWwA3wUs5w+4sPMoSXMt6xfThQC","padding":5},"hashCount":15}}}
11:24:30.866  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"targetChange":{"targetChangeType":"CURRENT","targetIds":[128],"resumeToken":"CgkIo9Kd9MDrggM=","readTime":"2023-11-30T10:24:28.916003Z"}}
11:24:30.866  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.866Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"filter":{"targetId":148,"count":7,"unchangedNames":{"bits":{"bitmap":"7q77Gtes4qpaXB3kJOrdc3r2BA==","padding":3},"hashCount":15}}}
11:24:30.867  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.867Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"targetChange":{"targetChangeType":"CURRENT","targetIds":[148],"resumeToken":"CgkIo9Kd9MDrggM=","readTime":"2023-11-30T10:24:28.916003Z"}}
11:24:30.867  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.867Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received: {"targetChange":{"targetChangeType":"REMOVE","targetIds":[4210],"cause":{"code":8,"message":"Too many outstanding requests."}}}
11:24:30.867  [2023-11-30T10:24:30.867Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x628b05cc received error: {"code":429,"message":"Too many outstanding requests.","status":"RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"}
```

Comment: Not enough info to give you a definitive answer, but your clients are most likely creating too many listen subscriptions too quickly and/or they're opening listening subscriptions but not closing unused ones.  While you can ask your CSR to bump up your quota as someone who's dealt with this error too, you need to look at your client codebase and monitor the number of open subscriptions opened and the rate they get opened.

Answer (score 1):

Having this number of active listeners in a client is an anti-pattern in Firestore. There are no hard rules or quotas preventing it, but it is just not gonna work very well (as you're discovering). There was a good discussion about this shortly after the release of Firestore, but I think it's still relevant and a good read: [Is there a practical limit to number of onSnapshot listeners?](https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/c/z4kRElB_DOg)

The solution is (as usually with NoSQL databases) to denormalize your data. For example, use the new [aggregation operators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries) to determine any count, sum or average you need, and use [write-time aggregations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) to determine any other derived values in a more reasonable number of places (either directly from the clients or through Cloud Functions). Also see [How should I handle aggregated values in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77461961/how-should-i-handle-aggregated-values-in-firestore)

Comment: We are aware of this, but it would be a huge undertaking to refactor our ODM to accomplish aggregations. Sadly, the app slowly grew into this mess.

Is there any quick workaround or setting to allow more requests?

Comment: Nope, there's no setting or quota - since this is not something that was hard-coded to be limited on the Firestore side either.