# How to use Sum () query in Flutter for Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am storing scores of a user in google cloud firestore as each score a new document in the collection named as "points".

collection name: points

> document1: {id:111, userid:345, value:50}
> document2: {id:222, userid:345, value:70}
> document3: {id:333, userid:345, value:30}
> document1: {id:444, userid:345, value:100}
> I want to sum all values in value field.

I have google many times but found nothing. Is there any alternative for sum () or any other way to implement total scores of a user?
Can someone give pointers right now I can only see support for NodeJS, Java and Web Modular Api

Answer (score 2):

The issue created by puf is completed now and the `sum` and `average` aggregation has been added. Please note that you need to upgrade the [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) package to ver 4.14.0 in your Flutter app.

As for the query on how it works. See example below:

```
double? points = await firestore.collection('points')
              .aggregate(sum('value'))
              .get()
              .then((AggregateQuerySnapshot aggregateSnapshot) {
            return aggregateSnapshot.getSum('value');
          });
```

With the new aggregation query, you can now reduce the number of document reads significantly.

Additional info on the pricing for aggregation queries, you are charged one document read for each batch of up to 1000 index entries matched by the query. For aggregation queries that match 0 index entries, there is a minimum charge of one document read.

For example, operations that match between 0 and 1000 index entries are billed for one document read. For an operation that matches 1500 index entries, you are billed 2 document reads.

The solution above provided by Kamrul Amin works but is not feasible because assuming you have 1000 documents in your firestore, that would incur 1000 reads instead of 1 read with the aggregation method.

Comment: Does sum work only for all of the records? How do I sum the value of points created between two dates.

Comment: Do you mean you only want to query documents that are created between two given dates? If that's the case, you just have to throw in the .where() clause before .aggregate().

To put it simply, you are querying documents where date is between date_1 and date_2, then sum the value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through your items in a collection and add the value. Something like this:

```
int total = 0;
void getData() {
  databaseReference
      .collection("points")
      .getDocuments()
      .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    snapshot.documents.forEach((f) => total += f.value);
  });
}
```

P.S. please always post your workings or your code when you ask a question.

Comment: Hello Kamrul, Thank you for your reply. However, this approach would increase my reads as it is going through each and every document looking for that particular field to be added. Am I right on coming to conclusion? 
I know about the write-time aggregation query which could be a potential alternative.

Comment: Yes, you are right but you need to go through each document in the points collection as each document will have some points that you need to add to the total. I have used these types of queries in a lot of real life applications and it worked like butter. You don't need to worry about the query as firebase has probably optimised it in their own way. If this answer helped you please mark it as an answer so others can easily find solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `sum` and `average` aggregation operators for Firestore in Flutter are still in progress. Work on it has started, but it hasn't been completed yet.

Surprisingly, there was no feature request on the [github repo](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire) for this yet - so I just added [#12074](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/12074). I recommend checking there for the latest status, and keeping an eye on the [FlutterFire changelog](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

---

Until the feature lands, your only option is to load the documents and sum the values client-side as @MdKamrulAmin explains in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77714722/209103) or to use a [write-time aggregation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation).

---

Also see my explanation on the various options for aggregations in [How should I handle aggregated values in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77461961/how-should-i-handle-aggregated-values-in-firestore)